# How would I turn this into a multiplayer game with up to 5 players?

Tags: java, oop

Trying to make this into multiplayer...Needs to be up to 5 players. I have the basics already, just cant figure out how to make it work for multiplayer. The ways that I tried we're not storing the guesses for each person. This is the stripped down version.

```
import java.util. * ;

public class randomNumber {

  public static void hint(int answer, int guess) {
    if(answer < guess) {
      System.out.println("Incorrect! \n TOO HIGH!.");
    } else if(answer > guess) {
      System.out.println("Incorrect! \n TOO LOW!.");
    } else if(answer == guess) {
      System.out.println("YOU GOT IT!");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many Players will be playing?");
    int players = players();
    int player = 0;
    player++;
    System.out.println("Player " + player + " Enter a number");
    int guess = guess();
    int answer = random();
    int count = 0;
    while (guess != answer) {
      hint(answer, guess);
      count = count(count);
      guess = guess();
    }
    hint(answer, guess);
    System.out.println("It took " + count(count) + " tries!");

  }

  public static int random() {
    return(int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  }

  public static int players() {
    Scanner my_input = new Scanner(System. in );
    return my_input.nextInt();
  }

  public static int guess() {
    Scanner my_input = new Scanner(System. in );
    return my_input.nextInt();
  }

  public static int count(int c){

    c++;

    return c;
  }
}
```

Comment: 'multi-player' is too vague.  do you expect each one to sit at the same machine and pass the keyboard?

Comment: Just like Randy said, it all depends on if you want them to be at the same machine, or for something like a server to handle the players across a network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a class, it's the first step in O.O. programming

But, all your methods are `static`, it's a limitation.

You have to remove all the `static` keyword but the main and to *instantiate* your game 5 times.

It's the second step in O.O.: the instances.

Once done you'll see some *details* need to be unique, you'll create a second class, instantiate one time. This class will be *in relation* with the 5 instances.

Walk on this way yourself...

Comment: Thank you guys, kind of rushed my question because I had to go to class, I'll be sure to make a note for the future. Thanks.